# Generating 0-5V Output using STM32F042F6

Tags: embedded, stm32, hardware

i need to generate a Sensor Output from 0-5V but I'm using a STM32F042F6. It's a 3.3V MCU.

Can I simply use a Levelshifter to convert the 0-3.3V DAC Output to 0-5V? I fear to lose resolution in that way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an electronics question, not a programming question. Ask on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and include datasheets to whatever parts you intended to use, preferably also a simple schematic.

Comment: Level shifter will not work

Comment: You do lose resolution by level-shifting in the sense that for each bit of change in the digital value, there will be a higher change in the analog output with 5V than there would be with 3.3V. But how much resolution do you need exactly? What is on the other side? Also, please note that there is no difference in effective resolution between a 5V 10-bit DAC and a 3.3V 10-bit DAC raised to 5V, provided your amplifying circuitry behaves linearly. Of course a digital level shifter will not work here and you will need an amplifier with a 5V rail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use OPAMP with gain 1.5. You need to have the 5V (or more) power rail.

If you use 5V power for the opamp you need to choose Rail-Rail opamp

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you reccomend a specifc OPAMP? 5V are available for supply.

Comment: look for an RR opamp with sufficient bandwith ans slew rate depending on your needs./